# $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X(H))$ for $X$ a cubic fourfold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

$\newcommand{\oh}{\mathcal{O}}$Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ be a cubic fourfold. I'd like to known the cohomology $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}_X(H))$ where $i : H \subset X$ is the ample divisor class.

One idea I had was to use the short exact sequence $ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_X(-H) \to \mathcal{O}_X \to i_* \mathcal{O}_H \to 0$ associated to the divisor $H \subset X$. Now tensor this by $\mathcal{O}_X(H)$ to get the sequence $0 \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X(H) \to i_* \mathcal{O}_H \to 0$.

I think we have $i_*\oh_H \otimes \oh_X(H) \cong i_*\oh_H$ at the end because $i_* \oh_H \otimes \oh_X(H) \cong i_*(\oh_H \otimes i^*\oh_X(H))$ by projection formula, and the pullback of a structure sheaf is a structure sheaf, but there can be no functions on $H$ with poles on all of $H$, so $i^* \oh_X(H) \cong \oh_H$ and thus $i_*\oh_H \otimes \oh_X(H) \cong i_*\oh_H$ (I'm not 100% sure this is right though).

Now take the long exact sequence in cohomology of the short exact sequence above. We have $H^i(\oh_X)=\mathbb{C},0$ for $i=0, \neq 0$ respectively, but I'm unsure how to find $H^i(i_* \oh_H)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $P=\mathbb{P}^5$, one has an exact sequence, $0\to O_P(-2)\to O_P(1)\to O_X(H)\to 0$. Taking cohomologies, one gets $h^0(O_X(H))=6$ and $h^i=0, i>0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can I ask how you get your exact sequence? Is this the correct reasoning?: since $X \subset P$ is a divisor, we have $0 \to I_X = O_P(-X) \to O_P \to O_X \to 0$, and since $X$ is a cubic, we have $O_P(-X)=O_P(-3)$. Then tensor the exact sequence by $O_P(1)$; this gives $0 \to O_P(-2) \to O_P(1) \to O_X \otimes O_P(1) \to 0$. If this is right so far, I'm a bit confused about the last part, namely how is $O_P(1) \otimes O_X \cong O_X(H)$. I'm guessing using projection formula, but I can't seem to write it down for myself in a believable manner. Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of $O_X(H)$?

Comment: $O_X(H)$ is the sheaf associated to the ample divisor $H \subset X$, where $K_X = -3H$.

Comment: @mathphys Your definition of $H$ is precisely my definition too.

Comment: @mathphys The key point is that $H$ (being the divisor that induces the embedding) arises as a hyperplane section of $X$ in that projective embedding. In other words, $\mathcal O_X(H)$ is precisely the restriction of $\mathcal O_P(1)$ to $X$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Right I see, that makes sense - thanks!